# AFNetworking 3.0 xml parisng getting response in nsinline data

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xml-parsing, afnetworking-3

I'm doing XML parsing using AFnetworking 3.0.
Below is my code.

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:Username, @"username", pass, @"password",device,@"device",token,@"devicetoken", nil];

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/soap+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xyz.or/webservice.php"] parameters:dict error:nil];

req.timeoutInterval= [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"] longValue];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[req setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[[manager dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (!error) {

        NSLog(@"Reply JSON: %@", responseObject);

        if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            //blah blah
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
    }
}] resume];
```

Now I'm getting the response in nsinline data.

```
JSON: <3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2231 2e302220 656e636f 64696e67 3d227574 662d3822 3f3e3c41 72726179 3e3c4469 633e3c49 643e202d 31203c2f 49643e3c 2f446963 3e3c2f41 72726179 3e>
```

Can anyone tell me what should i do to get the da

Comment: You have manager.responseSerializer httpserializer, so if you are sure that response is json you can set jsonresponseserializer

Comment: `manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];` What's the meaning of theses lines? Only the last one should be taken in account, no? You talks about XML (in your question), but all your code seems related to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];// remove this if no use
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]; // remove this if no use
```

Change

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

With

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```